# Bootstrap 4 Scrollspy not indicating on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to implement a bootstrap scrollspy. I think that I successfully implemented it, but it's not working. My menu items based on scroll position do not indicate. The active class is not added to the anchors. Can someone tell me where I am wrong and what to change in my code ?

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;
}
.scroll-area {
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
.scroll-area div {
  height: 300px;
    color: #fff;
}
.scroll-area div:first-child { background: green; }
.scroll-area div:nth-child(2) {background: purple;}
.scroll-area div:nth-child(3) {background: orange;}
.scroll-area div:nth-child(4) {background: blue;}
.scroll-area div:nth-child(5) {background: black;}

#main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
#main-nav li a {
  color: #000;
}

#main-nav li a.active {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <nav id="main-nav">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#a" class="active">Link1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#b">Link2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#c">Link3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#d">Link4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#e">Link5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
          <div class="scroll-area" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#main-nav" data-offset="0">
          <div id="a">Austria</div>
          <div id="b">Bolivia</div>
          <div id="c">Canada</div>
          <div id="d">Denmark</div>
          <div id="e">England</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scrollspy component looks for the `nav-link` class...

```
   <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#a" class="nav-link active">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#b" class="nav-link">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#c" class="nav-link">Link3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#d" class="nav-link">Link4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#e" class="nav-link">Link5</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/tqHAOdCNVZ

Comment: Thanks for the info